# Using ! with Cookies.get

Tags: javascript, cookies, js-cookie

I'm trying to use js-cookie to hide a cookie bar notice when user clicks ok.

The cookie bar has a class of .hide-cookiebar with display: none; so that it doesn't show up briefly when page loads even after the user has clicked ok.

Then I want to check for the cookie 'agree' and if it doesn't exist remove the .hide-cookiebar class. Then if they click OK add the cookie 'agree' then check for it and re add the hide class.

The first problem I've got is I can't figure out how to change Cookies.get to Can't get, I've tried using ! without success.

I'm hoping it will work after that.

```
<div class="cookiebar hide-cookiebar">
<span>Cookies are used on our website ... 
<a href="#">cookie policy</a><br><button id="ok">OK</button></span>
</div>


.hide-cookiebar {display: none;}


$(function() {

if (Cookies.get('agree')) {
$('.cookiebar').removeClass('hide-cookiebar')};

$('#ok').on('click', function () {
Cookies.set('agree', 'step1', { expires: 30 });

if (Cookies.get('agree')) {
    $('.cookiebar').addClass('hide-cookiebar')};

});
```

This seems to be working ok:

```
$(function() {

if (!Cookies.get('agree')) {
$('.cookiebar').removeClass('hide-cookiebar');}

$('#ok').on('click', function () {
Cookies.set('agree', 'step1', { expires: 30 });

if (Cookies.get('agree')) {

$('.cookiebar').addClass('hide-cookiebar');}

});
});
```

Comment: Where did you use `!`?

Comment: I tried - if (!Cookies.get('agree')) {

Comment: What happened? Btw, the code you posted has syntax errors (mismatching parenthesis), please fix that.

Comment: The cookie bar stays hidden and there's no sign of the cookie 'agree' in Chrome dev tools application

Comment: I've added another parentheses to this { expires: 30 })); I think that's right?

Comment: Actually I meant the closing parens of the if-blocks and the event handler.

Comment: I've had a play around with JS Hint and come up with this and it seems to be working. It looks a bit strange to me though, not sure if there are still errors. Thanks Bergi.

`$(function() {

if (!Cookies.get('agree')) {
    $('.cookiebar').removeClass('hide-cookiebar');}

$('#ok').on('click', function () {
  Cookies.set('agree', 'step1', { expires: 30 });

if (Cookies.get('agree')) {
  $('.cookiebar').addClass('hide-cookiebar');}

});
});`